# Merging dataframes to create longitudinal data set

Tags: r, merge

I have three cross-sectional data sets, and I am trying to merge them into one longitudinal data set. Some measures are constant (id, sex, community) and others vary over time (x1 and y). I would like to have a long-form final data set with one column for each of the variables mentioned above. I thought merge_recurse() would do the trick but it produces two columns each for y and x1 (although data12 and data14 merge as I had hoped... perhaps because these variables are renamed after the first merge?). Any thoughts on how to do this simply and quickly? Example data below.

```
#Constant over time
id = seq(1, 100, 1)
sex = sample(c("male","female"), 100, replace=TRUE)
community = sample(c("comA", "comB", "comC", "comD"), 100, replace=TRUE)
#2010
year = rep(2010, 100)
x1 = rnorm(100, mean=5, sd=1)
y = rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=2)
z = rep(5, 100)
data10 = data.frame(cbind(id, year, sex, community, y, x1, z))
#2012
year = rep(2012, 100)
x1 = rnorm(100, mean=6, sd=1)
y = rnorm(100, mean=11, sd=2)
data12 = data.frame(cbind(id, year, sex, community, y, x1))
#2014
year = rep(2014, 100)
x1 = rnorm(100, mean=7, sd=1)
y = rnorm(100, mean=12, sd=2)
data14 = data.frame(cbind(id, year, sex, community, y, x1))
#Merge each year's data
library(reshape)
#Create a list of all datasets
alldata=list(data10, data12, data14)
#Merge data from multiple dataframes
data = merge_recurse(alldata, by=c("id", "year", "sex", "community")

head(data)

id year    sex community              y.x             x1.x z  y.y x1.y
1  1 2010 female      comC 13.1771632561173 4.87556993759158 5 <NA> <NA>
2  2 2010 female      comB 13.7778630888456 6.69677435551805 5 <NA> <NA>
3  3 2010   male      comD 9.42440506678606 3.10067578314296 5 <NA> <NA>
4  4 2010 female      comB 11.0739409098036 4.12318001019941 5 <NA> <NA>
5  5 2010   male      comB 11.6015489242693  4.9565493450503 5 <NA> <NA>
6  6 2010 female      comB 6.52739602897104 3.76896148237067 5 <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: I think you're just looking for a `do.call(rbind, alldata)`??

Comment: It will be good if you can post sample output ie. head(data)

Comment: Sorry, my example data are somewhat misleading. My actual cross-sectional data sets contain variables not measured in each time period and thus do.call(rbind, alldata) doesn't work. It works perfectly if all columns are the same. The output from the above code has been appended above.

Comment: perhaps `ldply` from plyr is what you want?

Comment: Fix your example if it does not reflect what you are asking. That's what the edit button is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
all   <- do.call(rbind, alldata)
final <- reshape(all, v.names=c("y", "x1"), idvar=c("id", "sex", "community"),
                 timevar="year", direction="wide")

head(final, 3)
#   id    sex community  y.2010  x1.2010   y.2012  x1.2012   y.2014  x1.2014
# 1  1 female      comA   7.711    5.510   13.952    6.502   11.480    6.629
# 2  2   male      comB   9.130    5.672   11.470    5.500   10.295    7.338
# 3  3   male      comC  15.322    4.889   10.185    5.774   12.257    5.941
```

Comment: I want it in the long rather than wide form. As I mentioned above in the comments, the do.call function would work if all columns are identical. In my actual data set they are not. That is, some variables do not exist in some of the data sets to merge.There is not the symmetry that exists in the example data provided.